# How I can get upcoming song in Icecast ? (Icecast with MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, random, icecast

I am developing a webradio with Icecast. Idea is that you click on the song, and you get information (through mysql – more info than the metadata).

So far, I cannot find a way to “see” the upcoming list, so I am thinking to do it “manual” through MySQL.

```
A. I will create a list in the SQL with all info I need with a uuid
for each song, then I will add the uuid to the mp3 metada.

B. I will create a playlist with the exact order of the SQL and will
upload it to icecast. 

C.  I will display the song in the html and while playing I can grab
the uuid and mark it as “playing now”.
```

The only problem I can think at the moment is that I cannot shuffle the playlist, but it is minor to my project.

In order to avoid all the above, is there a way to "see" the upcoming songs (e.g 10 next songs) in my playlist with Icecast?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!
I'd advise to read [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps to edit the question afterwards, else it's likely that the question is closed or removed.

Comment: No, Icecast does not know 'the future'. It only knows what's going through it at that particular point in time. What you are asking for needs to be done on the 'source client' side, as that definitely can. Plenty of web interface or API enabled players/source clients.

Comment: Thank you TBR, can you please suggest one or two "API enabled players/source clients" so I know what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This can work.

Be aware that rows in SQL tables have no inherent order. If you want them in a certain order you must include ORDER BY in your SELECT statement. So

```
SELECT uuid, album, title, artist, tracknumber 
  FROM catalog
 WHERE albumnumber = 42
 ORDER BY tracknumber
```

Gets you the tracks on an album in order.

To  shuffle them randomly use `ORDER BY RAND()` instead.

Beware: `ORDER BY RAND()` performance is horrible if you use it for more than a few hundred rows in a result set.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, in my case the problem in shuffling is not in the SQL but in Icecast, if I select to shuffle the songs through Icecast it will shuffle the playlist but the order in mysql (that will be displayed) will remain the same. I will have a play list with songs 009,005,002 but in the display I will have 001,002,003